# Split a string in Java based on a separator unless separator is escaped with String.split

Tags: java, regex

I got a string in java that I would like to split in parts on following criteria:

- the '#' char is a separator
- if  '#' is escaped via backslash then is should not be considered a separator

i.e.

> "abc#xyz#kml\#ijk"

should be split into

> "abc", "xyz", "kml\#ijk"

I can do it easily with StringTokenizer and add some logic for the escape char but I would like to get it via one-liner String.split call with the correct regex. So far my "best" attempt is following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String toSplit = "abc#xyz#kml\\#ijk";

  String[] arr = toSplit.split("[^\\\\]#");

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

and the result is:

> [ab, xy, kml#ijk]

The last letter of the first two parts is cut out.

Any idea how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into lookbehinds?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      String toSplit = "abc#xyz#kml\\#ijk";

      String[] arr = toSplit.split("(?<!\\\\)#");

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: This only works for one escape, and fails when there are multiple escape characters in a row.